# Add value from textbox to csv file without replacing data

Tags: c#, file, text, csv

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    String[] bla = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\\chat.csv").Split('|');

    for (int i = 0; i < bla.Length; i++) {
        textBox1.AppendText(bla[i] + Environment.NewLine); 
    }
}
```

This code loads a csv file into `textBox1` and splits lines (|). I would like to add text to the csv file with the input of `textBox2`. So, the value of `textBox2` should be added to the last line in `chat.csv`.

```
 waarde1 = textBox2.Text;
 File.WriteAllText(@"c:\\chat.csv", waarde1); */
```

I tried to create (I am a beginner) something. The above code writes the text in textBox2 to the csv file but it also deletes all the current.

What function can I use so that the data won't be removed?

Comment: Please do yourself a favour and use a Libary for that, there a plenty out there

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `File.WriteAllText` use

```
waarde1 = textBox2.Text;
File.AppendAllText(@"c:\\chat.csv", waarde1);
```

This will open a new stream and append the text.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx) for more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to keep the text and add some new text?

```
File.AppendAllText("C:\\chat.csv", "newline");
```